# AWK PRINT command output

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am creating a file that has below output

```
SQL>  declare                        
  2   v_mail_id varchar2(300);            
  3   begin      
  4  SELECT user_mail_id INTO v_mail_id FROM XYZ where col1='Test';  
  5  dbms_output.put_line('EMail_Id'||' = '||v_mail_id);     
  6    
  7  END;     
  8  /   
EMail_Id = xyz@cc.com UTY@CC.com ITL@YY.com     
SQL> spool off;
```

Now I want all email id's in a variable and below is the command that I using to get the same.

```
Mail_Id=$(awk '/EMail_Id =/{print $NF}' date091217125531.txt)
```

Problem with this command is it is only giving me last email id but not all. Is there any way to get all email id's? and what should be the command for that.

Comment: I moved the text from your new question to here. And marked the new question as a duplicate of this question. Please delete the new question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're only getting the last email address is that this is what you're asking for with `$NF` (literally "the value of the last field").

```
mailid=$( awk -F ' *= *' '/^EMail_Id/ { print $2 }' file.in )
```

This uses `awk` to print the things after the `=` (with spaces removed around it). Using `␣*=␣*` as field separator will divide the line into two fields: the bit before the `=` and the bit after. With `$2` we may access the second of these two fields (you could also use `$NF` here).

With `sed`:

```
mailid=$( sed -n '/^EMail_Id *= */s///p' file.in )
```

The `sed` expression `/^EMail_Id *= */s///` will first locate lines matching `^Email_Id *= *` and then apply the substitution `///` to it. An empty pattern in the substitution means it will use the same pattern as was used in the range expression (`/^EMail_Id *= */`) and an empty replacement string means that the matching part of the input line will be removed.

The value of `mailid` will be `xyz@cc.com UTY@CC.com ITL@YY.com`.

If you're using `bash` and want to create an array variable, use

```
mailid=( $( ... as above ... ) )
```